# Invalid syntax (SyntaxError) in except handler when using comma

Tags: python, python-3.x, except

I have this code:

```
@app.route('/login/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    error = None
    if request.method == 'POST':
        session['username'] = request.form['username']
        session['password'] = request.form['password']
        try:
            # use reddit_api's login
            r.login(user=session['username'], password=session['password'])
        except InvalidUserPass, e:
            error = 'Incorrect username or password. '
        if not error:
            subreddits = r.user.get_my_reddits(limit=25)
            my_reddits = []
            for i in range(25):
                my_reddits.append(subreddits.next().display_name)
            session['my_reddits'] = my_reddits
            return redirect(url_for('index'))
    return render_template('login.html', error=error)
```

In 2.x, it worked fine, but in 3.x I get an error message like:

```
  File "app.py", line 101
    except InvalidUserPass, e:
                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Why does this occur, and how can I fix it?

Comment: read [PEP 3110: Exception-Handling Changes](http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/whatsnew/2.6.html#pep-3110)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Change

```
except InvalidUserPass, e:
```

to

```
except InvalidUserPass as e:
```

See [this](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/errors.html) for more info.

Answer (score 7):

Simply `except InvalidUserPass as e:`. And for heaven's sake, let's get rid of the ugly `error` thing:

```
@app.route('/login/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        session['username'] = request.form['username']
        session['password'] = request.form['password']

        try:
            # use reddit_api's login
            r.login(user=session['username'], password=session['password'])
        except InvalidUserPass as e:
            return render_template('login.html', 
                                   error='Incorrect username or password.')

        subreddits = r.user.get_my_reddits(limit=25)
        my_reddits = []
        for i in range(25):
            my_reddits.append(subreddits.next().display_name)
        session['my_reddits'] = my_reddits
        return redirect(url_for('index'))

    return render_template('login.html')
```

Answer (score 3):

In python3 it's:

```
except InvalidUserPass as e:
```

Answer (score 1):

In Python 2.x, the syntax `except ExampleError, e:` means that exceptions of the type `ExampleError` will be caught, and the name `e` will be used for that exception inside the `except` block.

In 3.x, the closest equivalent syntax is `except ExampleError as e:`. (This will [also explicitly delete the name `e` after the except block has ended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19142231), unlike in 2.x where it will remain defined.)

If this error occurs in your own code, simply fix it accordingly.

If this error occurs in library code ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19142231), [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34129348)), this indicates that either the library **does not support** modern versions of Python, or else the installation is **out of date** and upgrading to a newer library version is necessary. Please **read the documentation** for the library in order to check version compatibility, and do not try to fix it yourself (unless you intend to take over the entire project.)

Answer (score -3):

When getting the error

```
file /usr/libexec/urlgrabber-ext-down line 28
    except oserror, e:
invalid syntax
```

modify `/usr/bin/yum` and `/usr/libexec/urlgrabber-ext-dow` files by changing `#!/usr/bin/python` to `#!/usr/bin/python2`.

issue would be resolved.

Comment: _the issue would be resolved..._ Why? Please explain your answer a bit more also for future visitors of the page

Comment: This isn't just wrong, it's completely nonsensical - and it comes years after the one correct answer was given by multiple other people.