# Cassandra: "cqlsh" line 145 except ImportError, e: ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: cassandra, python-3.6, cassandra-3.0

Installed cassandra 3.11.1 version in Windows 10 with jdk 1.8.0_151 and python 3.6. All paths available in environment variables.
When I run cqlsh in command prompt, I get the below error:

```
File "C:\Cassandra\bin\\cqlsh.py", line 145
    except ImportError, e:
                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Anyone, Any luck with the above error?

Comment: Duplicate, Answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19142231/cassandra-file-cqlsh-line-95-except-importerror-e

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem.I downgrade python to 2.7 and it works for me.

ERROR:

cqlsh.py", line 146
    except ImportError, e:
                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: The codes (at least till Cassandra 3.11.7) are written for Python 2.x and it will be wise to downgrade to Python 2.7 rather than fixing the syntax. There are more than just line 146 of cqlsh.py that would need a fix, if you venture to make cqlsh work with python 3.x (I tried 3.8).

Comment: I too had same problem and after installing Python 2.7 problem fixed :)

Answer (score 3):

cqlsh requires a Python 2 interpreter. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-10190

Comment: Does that mean cqlsh won't be able to run for python 3.5 or python 3.6?

Comment: In its current form, only Python 2 is supported. The Jira issue above is to provide Python 3 support.

Comment: I updated cqlsh but now I am getting the below new error: 
"'\nWarning: Specified cqlshrc location %s does not exist. Using %s instead.\n' % (CONFIG_FILE, HISTORY_DIR) ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax"

Comment: For cqlsh version 5.0.1 (which supports only python 2.7) solution was to change cqlsh file header from ``#!/usr/bin/python3`` to ``#!/usr/bin/python``

Answer (score 1):

Ref: https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/errors.html

The error is correct as your syntax is wrong. It should be:

```
except ImportError as e:
```

Comment: I have modified my cqlsh.py file but now I am getting a new error:   
        print '\nWarning: Specified cqlshrc location `%s` does not exist.  
     Using 
    `%s` instead.\n' % (CONFIG_FILE, HISTORY_DIR)
                                                                                            ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Refer to @kermatt's answer, this will not solve the problem as the cqlsh package only supports Python2 for now. If you fix this line, there will be other errors and warnings.

Answer (score 1):

**My case:** I had to install Apache cassandra. I already had Python3 installed in my **D: drive**. With loads of development work in process on Python 3, i didn't wanted to mess my Python 3 installation. And, i needed Python2 only for Apache cassandra.

You came here looking for answer, so:

- I assume you have all prequisites installed for **Apache cassandra**, except **Python2**.
- You did not installed Python2 because you already have **Python3** up & running on your system.
- You are getting error when you are trying to run `cqlsh`
- You don't want to install Python2 because you don't want to mess up anything in/on already installed Python3.

Well i had same issues. Now, check my answer below.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/58285774/1513779

**Advice:**

1. Don't try `except ImportError as e:` in cqlsh.py as suggested above. You will be caught in loop of numerous errors & warnings. Just install Python2, following steps mentioned in link.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is because your Cassandra is referencing Python 3 installed on your system. To fix this, do the following..,

> 1. Install python 2 on your system.
> 2. Add python2 to your environment variables.
> 3. Navigate to your Cassandra bin folder eg `C:\Cassandra\apache-cassandra-3.11.9\bin>`
> 4. `py -2 -V` (verify that you have python 2 installed)
> 5. `py -2 -m cqlsh` (from your Cassandra bin folder.)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In case you have different versions of python I suggest this:

- Install cqlsh using

  python2.7 -m pip install cqlsh

This will install cqlsh in the context of your Python2.7

- Also you might need to install cassandra-driver as well the same way:

  python2.7 -m pip install cassandra-driver

Answer (score 0):

You can install python2 alongside with python3, and change the cqlsh.bat file in bin folder from python to python2 like this

```
@echo off

if "%OS%" == "Windows_NT" setlocal

python2 -V >nul 2>&1
if ERRORLEVEL 1 goto err

python2 "%~dp0\cqlsh.py" %*
goto finally

:err
echo Can't detect Python version!

:finally

ENDLOCAL
```

Note: To install python3 and python2, you can add both to path, and change python.exe in folder python2 into python2.exe

Comment: Great it works. But don't know if changing things like name of the executables is good practice

Comment: Simply install python 2.7 and add it to path. This worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

Better to hard code PATH in the batch/shell file 'cqlsh'. Or change the directory to the Python2 installed directory, like I did in the below code.

```
if "%OS%" == "Windows_NT" setlocal

cd C:\Python27
python -V >nul 2>&1
if ERRORLEVEL 1 goto err
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply install python 2.7 and add it to the path. This worked for me! Download python 2.7 from here [Python official download page](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-2718/)

Add location of python 2.7 to environment variables[image: Environment variable setup]
[image: Next]
[image: finally]

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem as you.
I had installed python 2.7 version as mentioned at [Prerequisites](http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/getting_started/installing.html#prerequisites)  and the error no longer appears

Answer (score -2):

First of all install python 2.7
set path in system variable `C:\Python27` in PATH key

Answer (score -2):

If you have Cassandra 4.0 installed use `sudo cqlsh`. It will work without any errors

Comment: This doesn't really answer the asked question, though, which was created before Cassandra 4.0 was released. Plus, you don't need sudo for a cqlsh session