# except ImportError,e: in django pyCharm IDE

Tags: python, django, neo4j, pycharm

Until now I have using pyCharm IDE tool for building web application.

I going to use neo4j for graph db. So I have installed neo4django.

After that I met this error. I faced to very critical situation.

what's the problem? How can I solve this problem?

```
bash -cl "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/python3.5 /Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pycharm/django_manage.py makemigrations /Users/sangwonlee/MW_Service_Dev"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pycharm/django_manage.py", line 41, in <module>
run_module(manage_file, None, '__main__', True)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/runpy.py", line 182, in run_module
return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name, mod_spec)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/runpy.py", line 96, in _run_module_code
mod_name, mod_spec, pkg_name, script_name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/Users/sangwonlee/MW_Service_Dev/manage.py", line 8, in <module>
from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 54
except ImportError,e:
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Process finished with exit code 1
```

[image]

Comment: I have no any change in  my init.py. I have tried to change , to 'as'. But another errors comes... so I rolled back.

Comment: no I tried ',' --> 'as'. ImportError,e: --> ImportError as e: but there is lot of another errors. so I back to origin.

Answer (score 4):

You seem to have an extremely old version of Django. The file that you've shown is not compatible with Python 3; but Django has supported Python 3 for three versions now. You should upgrade Django to the latest version, 1.9.

Comment: you are right. I have just installed django 1.9. Then the problem gone away. after that I have installed neo4diango. At last, I found what makes such a error. during the installation neo4django it make django version downgrade.