# Syntax Error encountered while installing package in linux terminal

Tags: python, linux, package

I'm trying to download the Turtle Graphics Package for Python, so I enter the following command into my linux terminal:

```
myusername@penguin:~/Pys$ pip3 install turtle
```

And here's the error I encountered:

```
Collecting turtle
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ff/f0/21a42e9e424d24bdd0e509d5ed3c7dfb8f47d962d9c044dba903b0b4a26f/turtle-0.0.2.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-c6dr99ga/turtle/setup.py", line 40
        except ValueError, ve:
                         ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

It seems like there's an syntax error in the file I was trying to download. Is there a way I can fix that?

Comment: Evidently the script was written for Python 2 and you're trying to use it in Python 3. In Python 3 it would be `except ValueError as ve:`.

Comment: See [Invalid Syntax in except handler when using comma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12519554/invalid-syntax-in-except-handler-when-using-comma)

Answer (score 0):

Turtle graphics is already part of Python standard library, you don't need to install it.

See: https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html

Just import it:

```
import turtle
```

Comment: Well, yes, but mine isn't the newest version. So I assume there's a need to install it?

Comment: what version of python are you using? What is the output of `import sys;
print(sys.version)` ?

Comment: it should be there already, it's been in the standard library for years now.

Comment: it printed `3.5.3 (default, Sep 27 2018, 17:25:39) 
[GCC 6.3.0 20170516]`

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be an issue with how the setup.py has been written.

To fix this, run

```
pip3 install turtle
```

Your output will contain a link to the turtle tar.gz file (https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ff/f0/21a42e9e424d24bdd0e509d5ed3c7dfb8f47d962d9c044dba903b0b4a26f/turtle-0.0.2.tar.gz)

run `wget <paste_link_here>` or manually download the tar.gz file from the link

extract the folder using 
`tar -xvf turtle-0.0.2.tar.gz`

go into the turtle directory and open setup.py in any text editor.

At line 40, change

```
`except ValueError, ve:`
```

to

```
except ValueError as ve:
```

then compress it the folder to a tar file again and then run pip3 install on the local file

```
pip3 install turtle-0.0.2.tar.xz
```

This should fix the problems with the package

Comment: You might require root permission to install it though